# Running Subversion on Windows sans Apache?

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, iis

We're stuck with a Windows IIS 6 server at the moment. We'd really like to get a decent OS version control system set up for it.

Can Subversion run without Apache? Most documentation that I've come across states that Apache is required, but I have seen a few mentions that Subversion can run as a stand-alone-server by itself alongside IIS. Alas, I can't find details on that particular configuration. Is that true and, if so, can anyone point me to some documentation on that?

Comment: subversion's good but distributed version control is all the rage these days.  any reason you're looking at SVN rather than Bazaar, Git, or Mercurial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion offers three primary methods of accessing its repositories:

- WebDAV (over HTTP) - This requires Apache, as far as I know.
- Local files - Networked files should also work as long as your repository uses [the FSFS backend](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.planning.htm) (which is the default).
- svnserve - This is a standalone server process that uses its own `svn` protocol.  Because it doesn't use HTTP, it can run alongside IIS.

For more details, see ["Choosing a Server Configuration"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html) in the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/).

Either the local / networked file option or the svnserve option should work for you.

Comment: Perfect...that's the explanation I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check out [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). It has every thing you need -- Apache, svnserve -- built-in and ready to rock. Easy to setup and administer.  Also, the [standard edition](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/) is free.

Comment: We can't use Apache, but maybe that's a loophole way to install it.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the reason you can't use Apache. Hopefully it works for you. It's a simple, straight forward solution and you can be up and running in minutes with it.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like a great option. I appreciate the info!